# Verificar se URL tem string

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, alert, indexof

olá, estou fazendo um código utilizando TypeScript e eu preciso fazer uma verificação para saber em qual pagina o usuário está, eu estou fazendo esta verificação de seguinte forma:

```
const url = window.location.href;

if (url.indexOf("/Menu")) {
    alert("aqui")
}
```

porém nao está funcionando bem... quando executo o código, vai para o index ne, na seguinte url: `https://localhost:44390/` e está me dando o alerta, mesmo sem ter o /Menu. Ele também aparece o alerta na página do menu, mas não claramente nao esta funcionando, já que aparece nas duas páginas. Alguém aí pode me dar uma ajuda?

O correto seria aparecer o alerta apenas na url `https://localhost:44390/Menu`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Me tirem mais uma dúvida se puder... Quando eu estou em uma página Index, no HTML, a url não aparece da seguinte maneira: `https://localhost:44390/Index`, ela aparece sem o `/Index`, ou seja: `https://localhost:44390/`... então como eu posso fazer um código que irá verificar se eu estou na index? Quando eu estou no menu, eu consigo usar igual no meu exemplo, porque tem o `/Menu`, mas a index não tem nada que deixe tao específico... como eu faço?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `.indexOf` é para pegar a posição inicial de uma ocorrência de uma string em outra string.

Ou seja, quando ele encontra a primeira ocorrência, ele retorna a posição inicial dessa ocorrência, que pode ser de `0` (zero) pra cima.

Quando não encontra nada, ele retorna um número negativo `-1`. Por isso você deve verificar se o resultado do `.indexOf` é um número igual ou maior que `0`, ou simplesmente é diferente (ou maior) que `-1` (caso queira retorno positivo), ou igual a `-1` ou menor que `0` (caso queira retorno negativo).

Ao colocar apenas `url.indexOf("/Menu")` no `if`, vai dar sempre *true* mesmo não encontrando nada, porque o número `-1` também é *true*.

Então deveria ser:

```
if (url.indexOf("/Menu") != -1) {
  ...
}
```

No caso do `.match` funcionou porque ele achou a expressão `/Menu` na string, logo retornando *true*, satisfazendo o `if`.

### Verificar se está no index

Pode verificar se o último caractere é uma barra ou não está numa subpasta com uma expressão regular:

```
.+\/\/[A-z0-9:.]+(\/)?$
```

A expressão verifica se existe um ou mais caracteres antes das duas barras (`//`), e após elas qualquer letra, número, dois pontos `:` ou ponto `.` (no caso de domínios tipo `site.com.br`), e se existe ou não uma barra `/` no final.

**Teste:**

```js
function teste(url){
   console.clear();
   if(/.+\/\/[A-z0-9:.]+(\/)?$/.test(url)){
      console.log(url, "está no index");
   }else{
      console.log(url, "NÃO está no index");
   }
}
```

```html
Clique num botão para testar:
<br><br>
<button onclick="teste('https://localhost:44390')">https://localhost:44390</button>
<br><br>
<button onclick="teste('https://localhost:44390/')">https://localhost:44390/</button>
<br><br>
<button onclick="teste('https://localhost:44390/Menu')">https://localhost:44390/Menu</button>
```

Comment: Ótima resposta, obrigado pela explicação, eu adicionei mais uma perguntinha relacionado a isso na questão... se puder respondê-la, agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Eu não entendi bem o por que do indexOf não ter funcionado, mas eu consegui dar um jeito utilizando o `match()`. Então funcionou da seguinte forma:

```
const url = window.location.href;

if (url.match("/Menu")) {
    alert("aqui")
}
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar a entender o porque, eu agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Então creio que ao utilizar o:

```
const url = window.location.href;
```

Você recupera o valor da sua URL em uma string, o `indexOf` serve para poder procurar um determinada posição então o valor 0 (zero) é uma possível posição o -1(menos um) que é uma posição inexistente.
Geralmente usado para procurar a posição de uma String no `array`.

Ao usar o `match` para encontra algo em uma String caso não encontre, vai ser retornado o valor `null` caso você encontra ele retorna uma valor correspondente que deve ser um `array` com objetos

Caso queira entender mais você pode dar uma olhada em alguns links:

Como usar o [indexOf](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_string_search.htm).

Como usar o [match](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp).

[Maneiras de saber se uma String tem uma Substring](https://medium.com/@switzerlandhero/5-ways-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript-523ac134f878).

Comment: Ótima resposta, obrigado pela explicação, eu adicionei mais uma perguntinha relacionado a isso na questão... se puder respondê-la, agradeço.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-the-current-url-with-javascript
Esse link tem como recuperar mais informações da URL então pode te ajudar se você precisar de mais alguma coisa.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde Samuel,

O `indexOf` é usado com strings simples, no entanto o `match` faz uso de uma expressão regular, claro que pode ser mais lento em comparação ao `indexOf`, mas o `match` pode te ajudar em situações mais complexas.

Da forma abaixo é possível que você consiga utilizar o `indexOf`, já que o mesmo te retorna o valor índice da posição na string.

```
const url = window.location.href;

if (url.indexOf("/Menu") > -1) {
    alert("aqui")
}
```

Abraços

Comment: Ótima resposta, obrigado pela explicação, eu adicionei mais uma perguntinha relacionado a isso na questão... se puder respondê-la, agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar.

`window.location.pathname`

Ele traz toda o texto da url, sem a parte do hostname e port, vindo apenas a parte após o dominio.

Exemplo: `https://pt.stackoverflow/qustion/`

Retornaria: `question/`

Desta forma você saberia qual página o usuário está acessando.
[Post Relacionado](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/)